# How to call the Wolfram Engine from swift?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, external-calls

I'd like to call the Wolfram Engine within a swift project in Xcode. Are there any known methods or available resources on how to do this? I'm hoping to include it as a resource library for use inside a MacOS or iPadOS project.

Comment: I don't know but I expect the answer is to train Swift to call a C function which in turn calls *Mathematica* (or the *Wolfram Language* if you prefer).

Comment: You can run Python in Xcode so you can use the Wolfram Engine for Python to call through.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this repo I wrote a while back:

https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/wolfram-server

In the "clients" directory there are examples for various languages (not for swift, but if you know swift you can probably figure this part out yourself).

Comment: This would require bundling the wolfram engine into xcode and building the app with it. This existed for ipados as CDFKit, would about for macos apps?

Comment: Also, a webserver doesn't work directly on files

Comment: You could use this: https://www.wolfram.com/engine/ ?

Comment: I get that anyone can installed the engine on their machine, but I'm developing a desktop app, so requirements need to be bundled within the .app file

Comment: Please contact Wolfram Research for (redistribution) licensing options (sales@wolfram.com). Technically speaking you can include Wolfram Engine in an app without too much effort.